Nextjs 14 generateStaticParams doesn't generate files
I'm on NextJS 14 with the App router, and I'm using output: "export" to generate static files for production. I'm using the generateStaticParams function inside /[id]/page.tsx to export static files for my dynamic routes.
However after building, I don't find the files in the out folder
See the result of build process:
 ✓ Generating static pages (18/18) 
 ✓ Finalizing page optimization    

Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                    99.1 kB         302 kB
├ ○ /_not-found                          870 B            85 kB
├ ○ /api/health                          0 B                0 B
├ ○ /conditions-generales-d-utilisation  1.29 kB        98.6 kB
├ ○ /ideesetconseils                     174 B          89.3 kB
├ ○ /lamarque                            25.3 kB         170 kB
├ ○ /leslessives                         2.32 kB         112 kB
├ ● /leslessives/[id]                    7.46 kB         159 kB
├   ├ /leslessives/9
├   ├ /leslessives/39
├   ├ /leslessives/23
├   └ [+2 more paths]
├ ○ /mentions-legales                    1.29 kB        98.6 kB
├ ○ /politique-de-confidentialite        1.29 kB        98.6 kB
└ ○ /reglement                           1.19 kB        98.5 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all            84.2 kB
  ├ chunks/472-31075e7adf75b534.js       28.9 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-986279e933d4449d.js  53.3 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-ff928e97f8293f3b.js  219 B
  └ chunks/webpack-f76f5768c7c52192.js   1.78 kB

[id]/page.tsx:
// Generate static parameters
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  try {
    // Fetch product data from the API
    const { data: products } = await getStrapiData("/api/products")

    // Map product IDs to static paths
    return products.map((product) => ({
      id: product.id.toString(),
    }))
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching product IDs:", error)
    return [] // Return an empty array in case of an error
  }
}

// Multiple versions of this page will be statically generated
// using the `params` returned by `generateStaticParams`
export default async function Web({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  const { id } = params
  const product = await getProductById(`/api/products/${id}`)
  console.log(product)
  return (
    <>
     
    </>
  )
}

next.config.mjs:
import withBundleAnalyzer from "@next/bundle-analyzer"
import withPlugins from "next-compose-plugins"
import { env } from "./env.mjs"

/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const config = withPlugins([[withBundleAnalyzer({ enabled: env.ANALYZE })]], {
  output: "export",
  trailingSlash: true,
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: { instrumentationHook: true },
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "admin.heritagefrance.fr",
        port: "",
        pathname: "/uploads/**/*",
      },
      {
        protocol: "http",
        hostname: "127.0.0.1",
        port: "1337",
        pathname: "/uploads/**/*",
      },
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "placehold.co",
      },
    ],
  },
  env: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL: "https://admin.heritagefrance.fr/api",
    NEXT_STRAPI_MEDIA_URL: "https://admin.heritagefrance.fr",
    HOTJAR_ID: process.env.HOTJAR_ID,
    IMPROOV_URL: process.env.IMPROOV_URL,
    IMPROOV_TOKEN: process.env.IMPROOV_TOKEN,
  },
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias.canvas = false

    return config
  },
})

export default config
console.log("Next.js config:", config)


Is generateStaticParams supposed to generate static files for dynamic routes in the 'out' folder?
